# Unable to load DLL UIAutomationCore.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Im getting a strange error on a XP on one of my application. The application is WPF application in C# using .NET Client 4. Im getting the error when the application starts, the application shows the UI and then crashes. The error comes from my trace log file. Anyone have seen this before?

```
Type : System.DllNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message : Unable to load DLL 'UIAutomationCore.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
    Source : UIAutomationTypes
    Help link : 
    TypeName : 
    Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    TargetSite : Int32 RawUiaLookupId(AutomationIdType, System.Guid ByRef)
    Stack Trace :    at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreTypesApi.RawUiaLookupId(AutomationIdType type, Guid& guid)
       at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationIdentifier.Register(AutomationIdType type, Guid guid, String programmaticName)
       at System.Windows.Automation.InvokePatternIdentifiers..cctor()
```

Comment: The c:\windows\system32\uiautomationcore.dll on that machine got whacked.  Typically by a rogue installer.  Copy a known-good version from another XP machine with .NET 4

Comment: Will it solve the problem by just reinstalling .NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for the same problem and found out this:
[VS2010 crashing](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/663208/visual-studio-2010-crashing-frequently)

According to the post there it says that you may have an outdated DLL of the UIautomation.
Also according to what was post there updating the DLL from here:[UIautomation download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13821)
solved the problem.

I hope I helped,

Sagi.

Comment: My application contains an installer, how do i know if its my installer or the client that has the problem. The application works on most computers does that suggest a working installer.

Comment: As far as I know the problem would be with the specific dll that got corrupted. as Hans said a good version of the dll from another computer will solve the problem.

Basically the problem may occur in other computers if their dll got corrupted too.
To be on the safe side maybe you should include that dll in your installation process and overwrite the one that already exists at the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

RawUiaLookupId is called by `UiaCoreTypesApi.UiaLookupId(type, ref guid)` to get the Id of the control then initial the AutomationIdentifier. UiAutomationCore.dll is commonly used in the implement of the provider plus your application is WPF application, so the issue is on the server side. Server side provider is generally served by the system. I am not sure whether make a windows update will resolve the issue. If not, we need to update this library manually.